# How to wait for a mousePressEvent (C++)

Tags: qt, c++11

I my Qt application written in C++, I would like to wait for a mousePressEvent to do something after the mouse pressed.

Would you please hehp?

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards.

Comment: do you mean, like wait until a widget gets clicked??

Comment: What is the problem with the [QWidget documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#events)?. Please ask your concrete doubt or difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the signal/slots to connect your mouseEvent to a specific slot.

Or you can create a QEventLoop and quit it by emitting "mSignalTriggert" when a mouseEvent happend.

```
QEventLoop l;
connect(this, &MainWindow::mSignalTriggerd, &l, &QEventLoop::quit);
l.exec();
```

Comment: mouseEvents are not signals, so one needs to override mousePressEvent() and call the code from there/emit a custom signal. The QEventLoop approach is almost always wrong and leads a plethora of reentrancy issues. Don't go there.

Comment: What do you suggest please?

Comment: I never said mouseEvents are signals. I'm sorry I thought it is clear that you use the mouseEvent to emit a seperat signal.

Comment: Thank you very much Pascal. I will try what you suggest. Kind regards.